# What are the cons of having a database server in a Docker container for production purposes?

Tags: mysql, docker

MySQL/Oracle/Postgres installed on a Docker container, in production, being referenced by other apps. What are the cons on doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers are intended to isolate environments used by different users and/or versions of software to minimize spends during the development time. Production server shouldn't be the home for everyone and shouldn't have different versions of software "just for testing". Therefore there is no reasons to put services into containers unless you are not a VPS-hoster.

Comment: And there is _some_ overhead for a container.